# How can I run my scheduled lambda only in one region though it is multi region

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I wanted to deploy my AWS architecture in multiple regions.
But how can I make sure application in one region runs.
its is scheduled lambda by Event Bridge Cron expression.

How can I make one region active(this will run regularly) another region passive(in case of disaster)
I tried to find solution I am not aware of any option for this

Comment: You will need to configure and manage the "multi-region" capability yourself. Very few services in AWS operate across multiple regions. You would be responsible for managing how region failover operates. You might be interested to watch [How Netflix Leverages Multiple Regions to Increase Availability (ARC305) | AWS re:Invent 2013 - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hAyA86QGRnI).

Answer (score 0):

To deploy your AWS architecture in multiple regions and ensure that your application runs in an active/passive configuration, you can use AWS Route 53 DNS failover.
Here are the steps you can follow to set up active/passive failover:

Create two identical versions of your application in two different regions, for example, Region A and Region B.

Create an Amazon Route 53 health check for each of the regions to monitor the health of the application.

Create two A records in Route 53, one for each region, with the same name and IP address.

Set the routing policy for the A records to "Failover" and associate each record with a health check. For example, associate the A record for Region A with the health check for Region A and the A record for Region B with the health check for Region B.

Configure the failover behavior for the A records. For the active region, set the failover policy to "Primary". For the passive region, set the failover policy to "Secondary".

If the health check for the primary region fails, Route 53 automatically switches the DNS resolution to the secondary region.

Set up an AWS EventBridge rule that triggers the scheduled Lambda function in the primary region. In case of a region failure, you can manually trigger the Lambda function in the secondary region to take over.

With this configuration, your application runs in an active/passive configuration, with Route 53 automatically routing traffic to the active region. If there is a failure in the active region, Route 53 switches the DNS resolution to the passive region, and you can manually trigger the Lambda function in the secondary region to take over.